# major US cybersecurity laws/policies since 2000?

Tags: legal

I am reading Cybersecurity and Cyberwar by P.W. Singer, and trying to tie the subject in with a government class project. I am looking laws and policies regarding cyberspace or cyber security, passed within last 15 years. Any recommendations? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this site](http://www.cryptolaw.org/cls2.htm#us) for a survey of laws on cryptography in the US. Cryptography is one of the most notoriously regulated parts of "cyber security".